# How can i add a timestamp to my copy column excel VBA code that updates each day the time, ignoring past days?

Tags: excel, vba, date, timestamp

how can i output the current date into a cell?

Special feature:

I use a column as a template, where the current date should be entered daily. If I copy the column, the current date should be transferred. However, the date of previously copied columns is not allowed to change!

Example: Column A is the template. I have just copied it to Column C with VBA, now today's date should be displayed!
Column D I have already copied several days ago, there should be the old date in it, as correctly displayed!
[image: Function]

goal is a kind of timestamp that stores the current date at the time of the copy into the cell

current VBA:

```
Sub ColumnCopyInsertNEW()
    
    Const ColumnsAddress As String = "D:E"
    Const LastColumnRow As Long = 2
    
    With Columns(ColumnsAddress)
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .Copy
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        .Cells(LastColumnRow, 1).End(xlToRight) _
            .Offset(1 - LastColumnRow, 1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` will give you today's date value.
Simply format to your needs

`Range("C3").Value = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")`

Comment: P.S. 
Storing dates is always better in the column...
In your case, you will end up with a very unconfy sheet to use after 1month only...
Also, excel hates if dates are not stored in format dd/mm/yyyy...
Any date interactions with formulas inisde the excel, will be tricky using your date format